# How to enter standby or hibernate mode in Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I just installed Server 2008 R2, and don't see an option to go into Standby or hibernate.  Is there some way to enable or access these?

Currently the only options appear o be shut-down or restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the following in an administrator console:

```
powercfg.exe -h on
```

Also see [MS KB920730](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920730)

With the HyperV role installed you cannot standby/hibernate and there is no way around this (that I have found)

Also, I suggest [Win2008Workstation.com](http://www.win2008workstation.com/) for some resources as I assume you are using in a non-server environment

<strike>Just running up vanilla install to confirm about hibernate/standby for a server product from MS</strike>

Comment: I tried both ways...it seemed to accept the configuration change, however, how do I actually put it into hibernation?  The standard shut-down options did not seem to change, it is accessed some other way?

Comment: I have never go this to work, but that's because of HyperV or running inside a virtual machine and not on hardware. Can you confirm you are running on the metal?

Comment: Yes, this is the actual O/S, not virtual.  Someone suggested this capability may depend on the video card?

Answer (score 4):

Provided hibernation is enabled as described in the earlier answer (powercfg.exe -hibernate on), you can also hibernate from the command line using the command

```
shutdown /h
```

The the [Shutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503%28WS.10%29.aspx) command doesn't have a sleep option though.

I've seen various postings suggesting that one of the command's below can be used to trigger sleep / standby but on my system it triggers hibernate and I think the behaviour is dependent on your system settings. The documentation for [SetSuspendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201%28VS.85%29.aspx) function describes the sleep capability but I suspect it has something to do with using [rundll32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787) to call the function. The "Standby" or "0,1,0" parameter is being dealt with as single string and SetSuspendState was not written in a way to support the rundll32 interface specifically.

```
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Standby
rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,0,1
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, it would be in the start menu....but sleep can be accessed by going to the desktop and pressing alt-f4....and then selecting sleep from the dropdown